# Can Not Create NFS Share on Additional Drive

Tags: mount, permissions, nfs, sharing

I have successfully followed the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-14-04) to share the example folders using Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 host (192.168.1.101) and Server 14.04 client (192.168.1.181: Virtualbox 5.0 VM).

However, when I try to share a mounted drive I get the following message:

`mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.101:/media/tim/big1`

The host's /etc/exports file contains the following:

`/var/nfs    192.168.1.181(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/media/tim/big1    192.168.1.181(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)`

I added the client mount folder:

`sudo mkdir -p /mnt/nfs/media/tim/big1`

I tried to mount the share as follows but got the error message below:

`sudo mount 192.168.1.101:/media/tim/big1 /mnt/nfs/media/tim/big1
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.101:/media/tim/big1`

The "big1" drive is mounted on the host on the /etc/fstab file as so:

`UUID=9e560067-2d79-4057-bf32-5ea93cf4d21b /media/tim/big1 ext4    rw,users,exec$`

Could someone please explain what I've done wrong? The "big1" drive is mounted fine when I'm connected directly via the host. I've got a feeling it's some sort of permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

I omitted "no_root_squash" from /etc/exports file which now reads:

`/media/tim/big1    192.168.1.181(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)`

The drive is now mounted in my virtual machine.